# How to display certain text on an adjacent cell when it is a statutory holiday for a timesheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a payroll timesheet with several Excel sheets with a similar format.

As of right now, I have a text box to input the payroll date and tables that would then autogenerate and list each day within a 2 week payroll period on a certain column.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a list of dates, and then display a specific text that would override any text in an adjacent cell when one of the listed dates appears on the column? Specifically, what I want is to display the text STAT on an adjacent cell if any of the cells on the column generates a date that is a holiday from the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered using a MATCH function perhaps?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what formulae to use. I'll test around with the MATCH function, but will it apply to all sheets if I have the list on its own separate sheet?

Comment: You might want to look at the WORKDAY formula as well. It allows you to add dates to a cell factoring in a list of holiday you setup in a list elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this,"to display the text STAT in an adjacent cell, if any of the cells on the column generates a Date that is a holiday from the list."*

**:Caveat:**

*Since you have not uploaded any sample data so that I've assumed Dates in Col T and Holidays in Col W.*

[image]

- Formula in cell U81:

  `=IFERROR(IF(LOOKUP(T$81:T$95,W$81:W$83,W$81:W$83)=T81,"STAT",""),"")`

**N.B.**

- You may replace Blank Spaces with an appropriate Text.
- Adjust Date list, Holidays & Cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have come up with a solution based on the information you have provided so far.

Pictured below is a basic recreation of the setup you described.

- It has an input date that you can change based on the current payroll date, with future dates in Column B:B that auto-populate for the next two weeks.
- In J3:K14, you have your list of holidays that can be changed or updated as you wish.
- The range K4:K14 is a named range I decided to call "holidays", but you could easily do this without a named range and just absolute reference those cells.

[image]

Now to get into the formula that is in Cell D5

```dart
=IF(COUNTIF(holidays,B5)=1,"STAT","text")
```

This formula is pretty straightforward. If uses an **IF** statement to evaluate if the **COUNTIF** function returns a value or 1 or not.

The **COUNTIF** function will evaluate as 1, so long as there is a matching date in Column B:B with  a holiday in Column K:K.

In the event the **IF** statement is true, it will return your desired text of *STAT*, but in the even it is false, it will return either a text value of your choice, a new formula, or a blank value.

- In the event you want a new text value: simply change the part of the formula that says *text* to whatever you desire
- If the event you want a new formula or another calculation to run when there is not a holiday: simple paste in the formula where it says *text*
- In the event you want it blank: simple delete the *text* and leave it as ""

  =IF(COUNTIF(holidays,B5)=1,"STAT","")

Also, it would be really easy to add conditional formatting in Column D:D to highlight the instances where STAT appears.

Please let me know if this works for you or if you have any questions or want any clarifications.

You should be able to reference the same holiday table across all of your sheets.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to use this formula and it worked across the other sheets

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you! If you get a chance, would you mind upvoting my answer since it was so hopeful to you.